# Why don't browsers hitting my Blazor WASM app download any webassembly?

Tags: blazor, webassembly

I recently built my first Blazor WASM (i.e. not Blazor Server) app. My understanding is that these apps compile down to WASM and then are served to the browser, where they run on a web assembly VM. Given this, when I use dev tools to look at what's downloaded from the site, I expected to see a web assembly file.

[image: My wasm site]

As you can see, I'm filtering by WASM in the pic, but no WASM appears. Am I misunderstanding how client-side Blazor works?

Thanks for your time and help!

P.S. If it helps to access the site, you can do so [here](https://morphwasm.azurewebsites.net/) if my quota isn't violated, which I keep doing on accident, somehow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the Application Tab and delete everything in the Cache.

Then open the Network Tab and F5.

You will see 1 Wasm file being loaded.

> My understanding is that these apps compile down to WASM

No, you will see them getting downloaded as .DLL files. The Wasm framework interprets the IL code in them.